# Check if MemberBinding's Expression is set or null

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees, equality

I have a `List<MemberBindings>` which I check for specific attributes.
Depending on the attributes, I want to check the expression and deciced whether to keep or throw away the binding.

Currently I have the following:

```
foreach(var memberBinding in memberBindings)
{
    // ... check for attributes
    var theExpression = ((MemberAssignment)memberBinding).Expression;
    // ... check if not set and skip
}
```

and I want to check if theExpression is null (meaning not set) but I don't get the point.
In DebugView it shows `{null}` for the `Expression`-property of the `memberBinding`.

Neither `theExpression == null` nor `theExpression.Equals(null)` returning `true`. Also tried `theExpression == Expression.Constant(null) / theExpression.Equals(Expression.Constant(null))` with the same result.

What am I missing here?

** Update (added screenshot of debug-view) **

[image]

Comment: What are the values of Expression in each object viewed in a watch window? i.e. add a watch to memberBindings. Also why are you casting the object to MemberAssignment. Are these a sub type of a base class?

Comment: @Wheels73 Updated my question and added a screenshot of debug-view showing the content of the MemberBinding in question

Answer (score 1):

The `Expression` property of the `MemberAssignment` expression is never `null`. When it represents a **null value** assignment, it will be of type `ConstantExpression` with `Value` property being `null`.

However, the `Expression` class does not override neither `==` operator nor `Equals` method, hence it's compared **by reference** and that's why

```
theExpression == Expression.Constant(null)
```

and

```
theExpression.Equals(Expression.Constant(null))
```

do not work (`Expression.Constant` returns a new expression reference).

Instead, you need to check if the expression instance is of type `ConstantExpression` (by either using `NodeType` property or `is` operator) and if yes, cast it and examine the `Value` property.

Like:

```
if (theExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant &&
    ((ConstantExpression)theExpression).Value == null)
```

or

```
if (theExpression is ConstantExpression &&
    ((ConstantExpression)theExpression).Value == null)
```

or with `as` operator:

```
var constExpression = theExpression as ConstainExpression;
if (constExpression != null && constExpression.Value == null)
```

Comment: Or even better with C#7, `if (theExpression is ConstantExpression ce && ce.Value == null)`